# OCaml Format and structural boxes: Why does my output not match the example?

Tags: io, ocaml

There is an example on the [Using the Format module](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/format.en.html) page on the OCaml web site that gives an example of the differences between structural and packing hov boxes.  I am trying to replicate this example.  (I am using OCaml 3.12.1.)

With the following input:

```
Format.printf "@[<hov 2>(---@\n@[<hov 2>(---@\n@[<hov 2>(---@,)@]@,)@]@,)@]@\n"
```

I get the expected output:

```
(---
  (---
    (---)))
```

What I can not figure out is how to get the output the page ascribes to "structural boxes":

```
(---
  (---
    (---
    )
  )
)
```

I was uncertain as to which `Format.printf` identifier maps to these boxes, so I tried several variations:

```
Format.printf "@[<hv 2>(---@\n@[<hv 2>(---@\n@[<hv 2>(---@,)@]@,)@]@,)@]@\n"
Format.printf "@[<2>(---@\n@[<2>(---@\n@[<2>(---@,)@]@,)@]@,)@]@\n"
Format.printf "@[<b 2>(---@\n@[<b 2>(---@\n@[<b 2>(---@,)@]@,)@]@,)@]@\n"
```

But all of the above give the same output as with the `<hov 2>` initial example.  Would anyone have any ideas how I can get output similar to the second example from web page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have thought that your second example (with hv boxes) should work. But it seems that @\n does not have the behavior we expect.

**Solution 1:** force the line break before the right parenthesis, i.e. replace @, by @\n.

```
let () =
  Format.printf "@.";
  Format.printf "@[<hov 2>(---@\n@[<hov 2>(---@\n@[<hov 2>(---@\n)@]@\n)@]@\n)@]@\n";
  Format.printf "@."
```

Result:

```
(---
  (---
    (---
      )
    )
  )
```

Problem: there will always be a line break, it will never print:

> (---(---(---)))

even if it has the room for it. If that is an issue for you, see solution 2.

**Solution 2:** Use longer lines :) If the break is caused by a long line then an hv box does break the line before the closing parenthesis.

```
let () =
  Format.printf "@.";
  Format.printf "@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------@,@[<hv 2>(---@,@[<hv 2>(---@,)@]@,)@]@,)@]";
  Format.printf "@."
```

Result:

```
(------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (---(---))
  )
```

However, the closing parenthesis is not aligned with the opening one.

**Solution 3:** If you want the right parenthesis to be aligned with the left one, you need
two boxes.

```
let () =
  Format.printf "@.";
  Format.printf
    "@[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @]@,)@]@]@,)@]@]@,)@]";
  Format.printf "@."
```

Result:

```
(------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )
  )
)
```